# Intellisense stops working (and references break) after compiling

Tags: c#, class

I have a web app in my solution with a couple of c# classes.
I've added a win app to the same solution and I did add a reference to the Web app in the Win app application.

When I code in the Win app, the Intellisense gives me the Web app classes and properties and parameters.  It will even complain if the parameter types are not correct.  No problem.

But as soon as I build my Win app, I get a compile error that "The name 'MyWebClass' does not exist in the current context".
If it doesn't exist why is Intellisense smart enough to pick it up.  Perhaps that's why it is called INTELLIsense.

What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps you could clean your solution? Or throw away the hidden bin and obj folders manually in all projects and rebuild. Perhaps that works?

Comment: Nope, sorry.  Not working.

Comment: Can you check if target frameworks are the same for both projects?

Comment: Also is good to look into Configuration Manager and check build checkboxes

Comment: Thanks Milosz - the framewords was different and it seems to have fixed the issues.  Pity I had to loose so much time on this.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is common behavior when one assembly targets a certain framework version (say .NET 4.0), and another targets a different version (say .NET 4.5). Check your projects' properties and see if they are different. If they are, make them the same.

[image]

Comment: I've had this happen in projects where we reference some old dll built with net1.1 and the project is in 3.0+ ..only solution was to dig out the old code and rebuild the dll, delete it and do without, or if possible remove the culprit dll from the references, but keep it in the bin folder on the production server for compatibility.